# How properly store and load own embeddings in Redis vector db

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, large-language-model

Here is a simple code to use Redis and embeddings but It's not clear how can I build and load own embeddings and then pull it from Redis and use in search

```
from langchain.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores.redis import Redis

embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings
metadata = [
    {
        "user": "john",
        "age": 18,
        "job": "engineer",
        "credit_score": "high"
    }
]
texts = ["foo", "foo", "foo", "bar", "bar"]

rds = Redis.from_texts(
    texts,
    embeddings,
    metadata,
    redis_url="redis://localhost:6379",
    index_name="users",
)

results = rds.similarity_search("foo")
print(results[0].page_content)
```

But I want to load a text from e.g. text file, create embedings and load into Redis for later use. Something like this:

```
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()

def get_embedding(text, model="text-embedding-ada-002"):
    text = text.replace("\n", " ")
    return client.embeddings.create(input = [text], model=model).data[0].embedding
```

Does anyone have good example to implement this approach? Also wondering about TTL for embedings in Redis

Comment: Not everyone can load images on the site. Please [edit] with code, as text, not images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello！ You can use the TextLoader to load txt and split it into documents!

Just like below:

```
from langchain.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores.redis import Redis
from langchain.document_loaders import TextLoader
from langchain.embeddings.sentence_transformer import SentenceTransformerEmbeddings
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter


embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()

loader = TextLoader("union.txt", encoding="utf-8")

documents = loader.load()

text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=0)
docs = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)

vectorstore = Redis.from_documents(
    docs,
    embeddings,
    redis_url="redis://localhost:6379",
    index_name="users",
)


results = rds.similarity_search_with_score("He met the Ukrainian people.")
print(results)
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems that the package requires the provided embeddings object to conform to  `langchain_core.embeddings.Embeddings`. Looking at the [source code](https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/_modules/langchain_core/embeddings.html#Embeddings.embed_documents), you could go about creating a custom embedder object by implementing the two required methods `embed_query` and `embed_document`:

```
from langchain_core.embeddings import Embeddings
class CustomEmbeddings(Embeddings):
    # pass any args/setup here
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model
        self.client = OpenAI()

    def embed_documents(self, texts):
        return [self.embed_query(text) for text in texts]

    def embed_query(self, text):
        return self._get_embedding(text)        

    # your custom get_embedding function
    def _get_embedding(self, text):
        text = text.replace("\n", " ")
        return self.client.embeddings.create(input = [text], model=model).data[0].embedding

embeddings = CustomEmbeddings("model_name")

# rest of your code as previous
```

Comment: OP means to store the vectors not to use a custom embedding function